# How to add multiple affiliations to one author in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, rstudio, markdown, r-markdown

I am using Rmarkdown to write a scientific paper. I struggled in add 2 universities to 1 author. After sexrch a lot, still didn't find suitable solution. My expectation just like this Authora,b.

```
---
title: my title
author:
- affiliation: group1
  name: Author1
- affiliation: group2
  name: author2

address:
- address: abc
  code: group1
- address: b
  code: group2
```

I hope author1 could have two groups as their address.

Comment: Not sure what default template rmarkdown ships with, but with the default pandoc you can use a custom template, the authors is even an example in the docs: see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#metadata-blocks

Comment: Thank you! The problem was solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes :

```
---
title: my title
author:
- affiliation: group1
  name: 'Author1 Author2'
- affiliation: group2
  name: author2

address:
- address: abc
  code: group1
- address: b
  code: group2
---
```

Comment: Many thanks for your code. I fixed this problem now.